# How to get client real ip-address and port using IOCP?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, iocp

I need to take ip-address and port of clients in server. Server written on C++ using IOCP, so I don't accept clients, I create new socket and then accept (AcceptEx) client on this ready socket. And because of it struct sockaddr_in is not correct.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AcceptEx` may return you both your and peer addresses (ip+port of TCP sockets).

```
BOOL AcceptEx(
  __in   SOCKET sListenSocket,
  __in   SOCKET sAcceptSocket,
  __in   PVOID lpOutputBuffer,
  __in   DWORD dwReceiveDataLength,
  __in   DWORD dwLocalAddressLength,
  __in   DWORD dwRemoteAddressLength,
  __out  LPDWORD lpdwBytesReceived,
  __in   LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

You should specify `lpOutputBuffer` to point on a buffer with enough size to hold 2 returned addresses, then . `dwLocalAddressLength` and `dwRemoteAddressLength` should be set to the address size reserved in the buffer.

According to MSDN the buffer size required for a single address (for `AcceptEx` function) is `sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN) + 16`:

> ```
> dwLocalAddressLength [in]
>
> The number of bytes reserved for the local address information. This value must be at least 16 bytes more than the maximum address
> ```
>
> length for the transport protocol in use.

Of course the buffer must be valid for the I/O duration. You may put it inside your `OVERLAPPED` structure. Something like this:

```
struct OverlappedAccept
    :public OVERLAPPED
{
    // some context information that you need
    // ...

    // Buffer for addresses
    struct {
        BYTE m_pLocal[sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN) + 16];
        BYTE m_pRemote[sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN) + 16];
    } m_Bufs;
};


// start accept operation
OverlappedAccept* pOver = /* ... */;

BOOL bRet = AcceptEx(
    hSockListen,
    hSockNew,
    &pOver->m_Bufs,
    0,
    sizeof(pOver->m_Bufs.m_pLocal),
    sizeof(pOver->m_Bufs.m_pRemote),
    &dwBytes,
    pOver);
```

After the I/O has (successfully) completed you may get the addresses:

```
sockaddr *pLocal = NULL, *pRemote = NULL;
int nLocal = 0, nRemote = 0;
GetAcceptExSockAddrs(
    &pOver->m_Bufs,
    0,
    sizeof(pOver->m_Bufs.m_pLocal),
    sizeof(pOver->m_Bufs.m_pRemote),
    &pLocal,
    &nLocal,
    &pRemote,
    &nRemote);
```